# Can we set different p-state governor to different CPU?

Tags: cpu, power

In my understanding, we can manually set p-state governor to performance or poewrsave.

Can we set different policies for different CPUs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.1-rc7/admin-guide/pm/intel_pstate.html

Each individual CPU is affected by its own per-policy limits

The global and per-policy limits can be set independently.